# How to bind. Tab solely = Tab, but Tab with other key = WinKey + other key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I want to remap my <kbd>Tab</kbd> key so when it clicked solely without any extra keys it will acts as Tab as usualy, but when I combine it with other keys like <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> it will behave like <kbd>Win</kbd>.

```
TAB = TAB (pressed solely)
TAB + (any_key) = WIN_KEY + (any_key)
```

Which tool I should use for this?

Comment: I haven't used it, but [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) sounds like exactly what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Goro in his reply listed good tools to recognize pressed key such a **xev**. But the second part of his answer wasn't what I was looking for.

I wanted to change the behavior of <kbd>Tab</kbd> not <kbd>Windows</kbd> key. For example to activate script in i3 window manager to change window I can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> + 1 to switch to the first screen. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (default). But I can still use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to make an indention if I press it solely.

What I did to make it works was using **xmodmap** and **xcape**.

```
spare_modifier="Super_L"
echo $spare_modifier
xmodmap -e "keycode 23 = $spare_modifier"
xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = $spare_modifier"
xmodmap -e "add Win = $spare_modifier"
xmodmap -e "add mod4 = $spare_modifier"
xmodmap -e "keycode any = Tab"
xcape -e "$spare_modifier=Tab"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two command-line based tools, [xev](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xev.1.html) and [xmodmap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xmodmap.1.html).

You can use `xev` to remap a key.
Start the terminal window and run `xev`, then press the key whose behaviour you want to change. In your case the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

`xev` will show you information about the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. such as:

```
 KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x75, subw 0x0, time 4090453521, (461,542), root:(468,620),
    state 0x10, keycode 23 (keysym 0xff09, Tab), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The third line is the most important, where `Tab` is the name of the behaviour the key is assigned to at the moment, the number keycode `23` is the internal id to recognize the Tab key.

or the information about the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x75, subw 0x0, time 4090816069, (681,389), root:(688,467),
    state 0x10, keycode 115 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Again, the third line is the most important, where `Super_L` is the name of the behaviour the key is assigned to at the moment, the number keycode `115` is the internal id to recognize Windwos key.

You can use `xmodmap` to swap two keys. Here is a [tutorial](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xmodmap_tutorial.html). For example:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 115 = Tab"
```

This will change the Windows key behaviour and make it behave exactly like a Tab key.
or

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 115 = Tab j"
```

This will change the <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> key behaviour and make it behave like the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.